# NSPredicate doesn't work for long long values

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have simple predicate like this to fetch all Code objects from Core Data:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "code.state != %@ AND code.validity != %d AND code.validity < %ld", "ACCEPTANCE", 0,  Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
```

Now inside `cellForRow` I am printing what I have:

```
    print("++++++++++")
    print(product.code)
    print(product.code?.state)
    let a = product.code?.validity ?? 0
    print(a)
    print(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    print(Double(a) < Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
```

And then I have the following result:

```
code.state != "ACCEPTANCE" AND code.validity != 0 AND code.validity < 4789427390557216924
```

```
++++++++++
aaa
Optional("PACKED")
1614253260000
1612447824663.5361
false
++++++++++
product test 5
Optional("PACKED")
1616880420000
1612447824672.909
false
++++++++++
Produkt testowy 1
Optional("UNPACKED")
1611788400000
1612447824678.4438
true
++++++++++
qqq
Optional("UNPACKED")
1612306800000
1612447824702.927
true
++++++++++
test phone 2
Optional("UNPACKED")
1612393200000
1612447824718.4958
true
```

As you can see two of them are printed as false. So why they are fetched while they didn't?

Comment: @MartinR you are a genius as always;) Thank you, it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `%ld` format in the predicate does not match the type of the argument (which is a `Double`). You have the following options:

- `%f` with a `Double`,
- `%ld` with an `Int`,
- `%@` with an `NSNumber`, that is the least error-prone method.

Examples:

```
NSPredicate(format: "code.validity < %f", Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
NSPredicate(format: "code.validity < %ld", Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))
NSPredicate(format: "code.validity < %@", NSNumber(value: Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))
```

Comment: could you please check out my question ? I need your solution as vaccine :(